# Envjs and Rhino in a Java application - Where to find env.rhino.js?

Tags: javascript, rhino, envjs

I'm trying to run [envjs](https://github.com/thatcher/env-js) and Rhino in a java application to render SVGs with D3.js.

So far, I can evaluate smaller functions using Rhino but when it comes to setting up envjs, the problems begin. The most important one is that the only tutorial for envjs talks about a file called env.rhino.js. But I have no idea where to find it.

Can anybody help me out?

(Yes, google shows some results but they are not officially belonging to Rhino or envjs)

Comment: I found it myself. The download is on the right side of the [envjs download page](http://www.envjs.com/release/envjs-1.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, download `env.rhino.js`.

Then, use this Java code to start a Rhino instance and load Env.js:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global;
import org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main;

Context cx = Context.enter();
Global scope = new Global(cx);
cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1); 
cx.setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_1_5);
```

Now you can load and run a JavaScript file (using its absolute file-system path)

```
Main.processFile(cx, scope, ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SOME_JAVASCRIPT_FILE);
```

And/or evaluate JavaScript code and get its String result

```
(String)cx.evaluateString(scope, "alert('Its WORKING!')", "js", 1, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is very late. But I want to do the same and had the same problems - maybe this will help the next one. It took a while to figure out which one of the hundrets of github forks on env-js will do the job. I found out that this combination will work for a simple test:

```
git clone https://github.com/thatcher/envjs-site.git
#note the different fork!
wget https://raw.github.com/thatcher/env-js/master/src/dom/sizzle.js 
wget http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

java -jar dist/env-js-1.1.jar
load("lib/env.rhino.js");
load("sizzle.js");
load("d3.v3.min.js");
d3.select("body").append("svg").selectAll("line").data([1,2]).enter().append("line").attr("x1", function(d){return d;});
document.innerHTML;

<html><head/><body><line/><line/><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><line x1="1"/><line x1="2"/></svg></body><line/><line/></html>
```

j

Answer (score 0):

I did attempt this but couldn't go very far. I also wanted to generate SVGs on server side, with requests being initiated from java(Glassfish in my case). The only way you can do this is with jsdom & Node.js. I am able to do this successfully. Sadly, other than Node.js + jsdom, there seems no other way to do this.

Once you get it working, there are bigger problems lurking if you try to heavily load Node.js with SVG generation requests.

Comment: Thanks Aejaz, I moved away from using Javascript SVG creation on server side. Instead I'm returning static links to internally generated pages that display SVGs. Nevertheless, you'd do the 3d.js community a big favour if you'd write a short article about generating SVGs using Node.js! :)